# List User Online Status

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, redis

I'm using Rails with MongoDB for database. In my apps I have 1 action for displaying list of users. User has `name`, `image`, `score` and `is_online` attributes. The list of users is displayed after ordering with multiple fields (`score` and `is_online`) and paging them.

I should now get all users and order by `is_online` and `score` and then paging them:

```
User.where(role_id: Core::Role.where(name: 'member').first.id).order_by([:is_online, :desc], [:score, :desc]).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

The problem are:

1. I think using pagination will ruin the list of users like a duplicate user in some page if the status is online or the score is changed.
2. If I remove pagination it will overload.

Should I using cache system like redis or else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few challenges here.

As you say, pagination will be wonky if a user's status/score changes between page requests. You could use [fragment caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) to cache the rendered pages, and serve the same content to all users for a fixed period of time. But this has a different drawback: Rendering is lazy, so page 2 (or 3, or *N*) will only be cached if someone requests it. So that's the same problem as before; sorting may change. Also, if the cache updates between page views, it doesn't matter that you're using a cache, since it's not that *same* cache version as was used in the previous request.

So what you'll want to do is run something that periodically rebuilds/-queries the *entire* list, a multi-version cache, and a way to lock a user into a specific version for his/her subsequent page views.

The tradeoff (besides more work) is that the list *will* be stale after a while.

An example of this is [stackexchange's rep leagues tables](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/86/month/codereview) which, while based on score, lags a bit behind actual score. You can decide whether that's worth the tradeoff.

Now, for querying periodically, I'd recommend

- using an [`ActiveJob` task](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) to do the querying at fixed intervals
- storing multiple versions of the query results as a hash in [`Rails.cache`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching), using a timestamp as key for simplicity
- a way of cleaning out old results, so stuff doesn't keep accumulating
- adding a param to page requests to identify the active cache version/timestamp (if blank, serve the latest)
- some means of telling the user "we're serving you a snapshot of this list as of [time and date]" - *and* a way of saying "the snapshot you requested is too old, and we've thrown it away"

In the end, it's simpler to only show unpaginated (but limited to top-N) lists with no caching. Or show lists that use a (more) stable sorting parameter (e.g. user name).